# Liferay 6.1, Asset tag from deleted document version appears in the new version

Tags: caching, liferay

I am using liferay 6.1.2. A document was created and it get published by user so the version get created let exa 2.0.

Now user  again start a new revision for the same document and edit by adding some new tag and some category in it and document get saved with version id 2.1.

Now user again delete 2.1 version document from draft and again start a new revision on top of 2.0 version.

Again 2.1 version get created but here the problem is in tag the last tag added in (2.1 which already get deleted ) also appear here.

Correct behavior it should get all data from 2.0 version which is already get published.

Could any one suggest what i need to do to fix this issue.

1. I have try to clear the cache from Control pannel
2. By implementing MultiVMPoolUtil.clear();
3. By adding below properties in portal-ext.properties file

   ```
   table.mapper.cacheless.mapping.table.names=AssetEntries_AssetCategories,AssetEntries_AssetTags
   ```

Comment: Please note that Liferay 6.1.2 was released in 2013 and is now unmaintained. Also, as no custom code is involved, it's [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stackoverflow. Update to the latest version and try to reproduce there. This has the positive side effect that you're also getting rid of security issues that have been fixed since then.

Comment: @OlafKock it's not pretty fair to tell to upgrade only, probably he knows that new version exists but he cannot migrate.
Maybe he can try to search for known issues here: https://issues.liferay.com/issues/ for 6.1 version.
And it's possible to fix the portal using ext or service wrapper..

Comment: @daniele I understand the sentiment, but my assumption is that most people who are using ancient versions should be pointed to the newer releases, if only to make it known to them and their project leads that they are missing critical fixes in a version that has now been stale for 5.5 years. You're right with the search for issues, but even backporting an existing fix in an ext would leave all the other fixed issues open, in internet facing software. I still believe that staying more up to date is superior to fixing an individual ancient issue.

Comment: @Olaf Koack Thanks for your quick reply . I can understand that we ae using old version .. but migration is not the solution for this problem. Can you give me proper solution .. if any.

Answer (score 1):

This is not per see a bug in Liferay but more about how it was architectured. The asset properties, which include tag and categories, are not versionned with the document itself. You can see that in the database where you have only one `Asset` linked to all your `DLFileEntry` version. AFAIK, this is still the same in 7.1 and probably even 7.2 and also apply to web contents.